# How to show total pages in JSON response in Django Pagination?

Tags: django, serialization, pagination

I am currently working on pagination in Django restful framework. I am successfully done with pagination. but the problem I am facing is that "JSON response does not include information about total pages in my query and other information like total records etc". how can I include this information in my response.
my view.py is

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
#######################View all mobiles
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAll_Mobiles(request):
    try:
        Mobile_all = Mobile.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(Mobile_all, 10)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            users = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            users = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999),
            # deliver last page of results.
            users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = Mobile_Serializer(users,many=True,context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except Mobile.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

and my API returns record on changing page in URL. but it does not give me response information.
Can anybody please tell me how to include this information in response. I will be very thankful for this favour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       if serializer.data["hasPagination"]:
            paginator = Paginator(result_serializer.data, settings.PAGE_SIZE)
            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
            result = paginator.get_page(page)
            return Response(data={
                'results': result.object_list,
                'total_records': paginator.count,
                'total_pages': paginator.num_pages,
                'page': result.number,
                'has_next': result.has_next(),
                'has_prev': result.has_previous()
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the number of pages with `self.page.paginator.num_pages` inside a serializer, at it's an attribute of the paginator.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look how this is [done](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.3/rest_framework/pagination.py#L228) by DRF itself.

In your example, the implementation may look like this:

```
#users is a Page object returned from the django paginator class
#its not a list of users, it just act as a list of users when iterated
return Response({
    'count': paginator.count,
    'num_pages': paginator.num_pages,
    'results': serializer.data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is :

```
# instead of returning serializer data instantly:
# return Response(serializer.data)
res = {'data': serializer.data, 'pages_count': paginator.num_pages()}
return Response(res)
```

Another way is overwrite `to_represntation` method in your serializer...

Comment: Its giving error like "update is not property of 'res' ".

Comment: but i am done with below answer. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @AmadudDin You'r right :)
It was my mistake, I edited my answer for further uses.